# Reading the Excel cell dropdown values from macro

Tags: excel

I have an excel file in which i have a cell which is a list and has values say "USA", "India", "Europe", "London".
I want to read all the dropdown values present in this cell from a macro... can anyone assist me please??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your list in the excel sheet has been created using `Data` > `Validation`?

Assuming you have a list in cell A1 on your spreadsheet the following code will retrieve all values in the list.

```
Sub GetDropDownListValues()
    Dim sourceList As Range
    Set sourceList = Evaluate(Range("A1").Validation.Formula1)

    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In sourceList
        Debug.Print cl
    Next cl

End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Remnant... but my formula in the Validation is having an IF condition like IF(A1="Fruit", A2=Fruit_Range, A2=Fruit_Vegetable)

Comment: Ok. So is the list populated using a named range? i.e. Fruit_Range or Fruit_Vegetable...